# Silex "hello world" - 404

Tags: apache, .htaccess, php, silex, linux

На свежую fedora 21 накатил AMP, скачал silex, создал virtualhost.
Вот конфиг:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName film.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/video/web/
</VirtualHost>
```

В web положил .htaccess с содержимым:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /video/web
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

В url вбил `film.dev/hello`, однако получил 404.
В файле `web/index.php` поменял:

```
$app->get('/hello'
```

на

```
$app->get('/'
```

работает.

Подскажите, как можно решить проблему с редиректом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А зачем Вы в RewriteBase повторяете часть корневого пути? По идее, там должен быть просто "корень" директории хоста, а она у Вас располагается в `/var/www/html/video/web/`.

Думаю, будет достаточно указать там "/".

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```